# Get remote HEAD with libgit2?

Tags: head, git-remote, libgit2

I can't seem to figure out how to get a `git_reference *` to a particular remote's HEAD.

I've got:

```
git_repository * repo = NULL;
git_reference *   ref = NULL;

/* ...load repository... */

if(git_reference_lookup(&ref, repo, "remotes/origin/HEAD"))
    printf("Error obtaining reference to remote HEAD!");
```

The error message is displayed when the application is run, indicating that the reference wasn't found. However, the remote HEAD does indeed exist:

```
$: find .git/refs/*
.git/refs/heads
.git/refs/heads/master
.git/refs/remotes
.git/refs/remotes/origin
.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
.git/refs/tags
```

Why can't I obtain a `git_reference *` to the remote HEAD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a full path to the reference.  For example:

```
int error = git_reference_lookup(&ref, repo, "refs/remotes/origin/HEAD");
```

libgit2 could not prefix `refs/` for you, or else you would be unable to open references in other places, most notably the `HEAD` reference.

Comment: Ah, okay - thanks for the clarification! I was actually just returning to this question to post an answer saying the same thing. I used `git_reference_list()` to enumerate all of the references in the repository and was able to get the correct string to use from there.